# Login loop after setting to unsopported resolution with randr -s

Tags: display-resolution, randr

This is my first day with Ubuntu 20.04. I was researching in google for a feature like AMD virtual resolution and came with randr and tested it.

I set it to unsupported resolution, and I got "input is not supported". I tried using google chrome remote but no luck. I restarted after that and that's where the login loop began for me.

I uninstalled gdm3 and installed lightdm and not it wont even boot to os. i do plan on reinstalling but just in case on future this happened again what fixes can i do?

Answer (score 0):

it happend to me too when i started using ubuntu
restart your computer
on login screen  press ctrl+alt+f3
enter your user name and password there

now enter the xrandr command to set the display size you want